# How to use table data using DisplayTag

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, displaytag

I am newbie in struts.I have created table using Display tag ,It populates the data from action class using arraylist.
I want to use the previous column data(display:column),and fill the next column data on the basis onf previous column value.but I am not getting how to get the previous column value in display column.

```
<display:table name="sessionScope.studentList" export="true" requestURI="StudentDisplay">   
    <display:column property="studentFullName" title="Name"></display:column>
    <display:column property="studentMobile" title="Mobile No"></display:column>
    <display:column property="studentResidence" title="Residence No"></display:column> </display:table>
```

Comment: What is the source code supposed to show?

Answer (score 0):

you can access using paramID and based on that paramId you can do any modification using jquery